# Type of mic i am using to mic up a acoustic guitar . And were best to have them around the guitar

Tags: guitar

The mics I am using are, a k g c1000, sure pg58 and a pulse pm1800t.THE guitar is a Martin 00028ec , Mainly for doing gigs but also some recording , JA

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I learnt a lot from this excellent video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ko6ceHqLbA

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly, the mic setups for acoustic guitar would be:

- **Single Condenser**: With a single condenser microphone, such as your AKG C100S, you would typically place this directly in front of the sound hole, about 3-4 inches from the body of the guitar (to allow room for picking/strumming)
- **Double Condenser**: When recording with two (typically smaller cardioid) condenser microphones, a stereo recording can be achieved by placing these in front of the guitar, at approximately 45-degree angles from the sound-hole, anywhere up to 8 inches from the sound hole
- **Single/multiple Dyanamic Microphones**: Using dynamic microphones like your PG58 or PM1800T set, you'll find that these don't have the same sensitivity or frequency response as a condenser microphone, so dynamic microphones are rarely used for micing acoustic guitar. But if you wanted to use these, you'll have to get these very close to the guitar to get a good response, so the best position might be closer to the neck, placing it nearly parallel to the neck with the microphone head between your picking hand and the fretboard, so it's not in the way of your picking/strumming

Thanks for asking this! The best way to get a recording that sounds good to you is to experiment, so although I've given you some advice here, please experiment with other configurations and discover what works best for you.

Welcome to the site!

Comment: This answer is good but OP says they would like to record with this set up but also gig. Using condensers (depending on the pattern) may not be suitable for live situations. They are typically more sensitive and you may run into feedback issues. Phantom power may also be a problem in a live setting. Would stink to get to a gig and find the sound person has no way of getting power to the mic you brought.